# Trying to understand map function for collection of structs

Tags: swift

Please can someone explain the following code like I'm 5. I know what it's doing, changing all isLocked Bools to true in a struct array of type `Person`. I'm just having trouble with "storytelling" the syntax to myself.

```
people = people.map({
        (p) -> Person in
        var mod = p
        mod.isLocked = true
        return mod
})
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`map` lets you make a new array from an existing one by applying some transform closure to all of its elements. Unfortunately, in this example, your closure is returning the same elements that it takes, so if your `Person` is a `class` (rather than a `struct`), the `map` is completely unnecessary, and the code above will simply do the same thing as:

```
people.forEach { $0.isLocked = true }
```

If `Person` were a `struct` instead of a `class`, OTOH, then the `map` would have meaning, because you'd need to make a copy of each of the objects in order to modify it.

In the case of a `struct`, the `map` creates a new array consisting of copies of each `Person` struct in the array, with each copying having its `isLocked` property set to `true`:

```
people = people.map {
    (p) -> Person in
    var mod = p // make a copy of each Person, store it in 'mod'
    mod.isLocked = true // change the isLocked property of the copy to true
    return mod // return the modified copy
}
```

Comment: OK. Thanks! I'm going to modify the question to specify struct. I still need clarity on the syntax for it.